# Numpy is installed, but can't be imported from script

Tags: python, numpy

I have a simple script that imports numpy. I execute the script from console `python3.8 main.py` and i got this message:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'**

However, if I run python3.8 in console, and I import numpy, it works well.

I tried to install numpy for python3.11 as follow:

```
$ python3.11 -m pip3 install numpy
/usr/local/bin/python3.11: No module named pip3
```

also tried:

```
$ python3.8 -m pip3 install numpy
/usr/bin/python3.8: No module named pip3
$ pip3 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in */.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.24.4)
```

However, i can't import numpy from my script

I have Ubuntu 20.
In my system I have all of this:

```
python
python2.7
python3.11
python3.8
python3-config
python3-pasteurize
python2
python3
python3.11-config
python3.8-config
python3-futurize
```

Comment: Use `python3.8 -m pip install numpy`. The module is *always* called `pip`; it's just that executable might be named `pip`, `pip3` or `pip3.8`, to distinguish it from other `pip` executables.

Comment: Your `pip3` executable that you use in `pip3 install numpy` is probably for yet another Python. Try `pip3 --version` to see what version of Python that suggests. (It's probably for Python 3.11 instead.)

Comment: What's in the script? Is it just `import numpy` or is there more to it? For example, if it manipulates `sys.path`, that could easily cause the problem. It might help to post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). And are you running the same code in the console? `import numpy` or?

Comment: Why does pip say `*/`? I don't know what the star would mean. Is that a typo, and it's supposed to say `./`?

Comment: @9769953 *"It's probably for Python 3.11 instead."* - That's what I thought at first too, but looking at the `pip3` output, it has `python3.8` in the location. Still, might as well check `pip3 --version`.

Comment: I've tried everything that you suggested, but they didn't work. My alternative solution was to install virtual environment, and then everything work well. The script was just import jumpy, create an array of zeros and print it.